# c# Multiple calls to a javascript function not working

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net

On a click event I call the same JavaScript function 3 times but the javascript function itself only execute once.

```
BLL.Common.executeJSFunction("DoSomething();");
BLL.Common.executeJSFunction("DoSomething();");
BLL.Common.executeJSFunction("DoSomething();");
```

The method:

```
public static void executeJSFunction(string jsFunction)
    {
        var page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), "Exec", jsFunction, true);
    }
```

Java script function:

```
function DoSomething()
{
   alert('Hello Word');
}
```

ps: There is a ScriptManager and a update panel on the page just in case....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You overwrite the key with each function call, try:

```
BLL.Common.executeJSFunction("DoSomething();", "Exec1");
BLL.Common.executeJSFunction("DoSomething();", "Exec2");
BLL.Common.executeJSFunction("DoSomething();", "Exec3");

public static void executeJSFunction(string jsFunction, string key)
{
    var page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), key, jsFunction, true);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is happening because you're assigning the same key (`"Exec"`) to the scripts. Assign a different key for each, or just do this:

```
BLL.Common.executeJSFunction("DoSomething();DoSomething();DoSomething();");
```

Answer (score 4):

Right now you are registering the same code 3 times under the key `Exec`. You need to use different keys for your script registration:

```
public static void executeJSFunction(string key, string jsFunction)
    {
        var page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), key, jsFunction, true);
    }

BLL.Common.executeJSFunction("Exec1", "DoSomething();");
BLL.Common.executeJSFunction("Exec2", "DoSomething();");
BLL.Common.executeJSFunction("Exec3", "DoSomething();");
```

See more here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310408.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use different RegisterStartupScript method's key parameter value on each executeJSFunction method call. You may use this: `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), jsFunction, true);`

Comment: thx yuri, since I tried @JamesJohnson solution first I will mark his as resolved! but thx a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem is being caused because you're passing the same 'key' parameter ("Exec") each time you call the  `RegisterStartupScript` function.

See here for further info - http://forums.asp.net/t/1365260.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

If we need to call a javascript function more than once from c#,we must have to change the key parameter(3rd parameter),because browser will consider it as a same request and it will not process that request.Consider the below LOC

```
   var key="firstRequest";
    var page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), key, "FunctionName()",true);
```

Now we have to change the key to call the same function again,

```
   key="secondRequest";
   var page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), key, "FunctionName()",true);
```